# Problema al utilizar el método "del" de las listas (error de fuera de rango de la lista)

Tags: python, lista

Me funciona bien el borrado, lo único es que no sé qué hacer para que no me de el error de fuera de rango.

PD: esto es una prueba que he hecho yo aparte, tratando de solucionar un ejercicio más complejo. Se agradecerían soluciones

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = int(input("n: "))
```

Quiero conseguir borra un elemento del indice de la lista que sea igual al valor de n

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if n == lista[i]:
        del lista[i]
    print(lista[i])
```

Comment: nunca borres elementos de una lista si iteras, ya que el tamaño varía y por eso es que tienes error de que el elemento está fuera del rango de la lista.

Answer (score 2):

Regla fundamental: nunca hay que borrar elementos de una lista mientras se está iterando.

Hay varias formas para borrar un elemento:

1.- **método `.remove()`**: sólo borra el primer elemento que encuentra, por lo que si queremos borrar todos habrá que hacer un bucle:

```py
while n in lista:
    lista.remove(n)
```

2.- **comprensiones de lista**: Con un filtrado se pueden excluir los elementos iguales.

```py
lista = [i for i in lista if i != n]
```